# How to get node having a child node having a specified text?

Tags: xpath

There is a xml :

```
<mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
  <mgns1:CODE_CS>1</mgns1:CODE_CS>
  <mgns1:VALEUR_CS>2</mgns1:VALEUR_CS>
</mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
<mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
  <mgns1:CODE_CS>2</mgns1:CODE_CS>
  <mgns1:VALEUR_CS>M</mgns1:VALEUR_CS>
</mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
<mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
  <mgns1:CODE_CS>3</mgns1:CODE_CS>
  <mgns1:VALEUR_CS>LOC</mgns1:VALEUR_CS>
</mgns1:Champ_supplementaire>
```

I want to get the node `mgns1:Champ_supplementaire` having a child `mgns1:CODE_CS` which text's is `2`. How to do that ?

I tried

```
NodeList nodeliste_cs2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( "//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[//mgns1:CODE_CS=2]//mgns1:VALEUR_CS",doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: `NodeList nodeliste_cs2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( "//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[//mgns1:CODE_CS=2]//mgns1:VALEUR_CS",doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

Comment: Try `"//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[mgns1:CODE_CS=2]/mgns1:VALEUR_CS"`

Comment: When do we use `//` ?

Comment: Simple put, to select node *anywhere in DOM*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//node_foo[//node_bar=2]`

means *select first found `node_foo` if there is a `node_bar` with value `2` **anywhere in DOM***

`//node_foo[node_bar=2]`

means *select first found `node_foo` if it has **its own child** `node_bar` with value `2`*

So you need

```
"//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[mgns1:CODE_CS=2]/mgns1:VALEUR_CS"
```

Comment: I get Nullpointerexception when trying to get `NodeList nodeliste_cs3 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( "//mgns1:Champ_supplementaire[mgns1:CODE_CS=3]/mgns1:VALEUR_CS",doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

Comment: @pheromix , I don't know which tool you're using and how it deals with namespaces, so try the same ignoring namespaces `"//*[name()='Champ_supplementaire' and *[name()='CODE_CS' and.=2]/*[name()='VALEUR_CS']"`